# Is there a way to get Visual Studio 2008 to stop formatting my AutoProperties?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-formatting, automatic-properties

In Visual Studio 2008's Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting, I have the following settings ticked.

- Automatically format completed statement on ;
- Automatically format completed block on }

This is really helpful for when I'm writing a method or a for/foreach/while/if statement.

ie if I write

```
void MyMethod(){}
```

I want it to reformat it to the following when I type the last }

```
void MyMethod()
{
}
```

However, when I write:

```
bool MyProperty { get; set; }
```

I want it to stay that way instead of getting changed to:

```
bool MyProperty 
{ 
    get; 
    set; 
}
```

Is there anyway that I can get this to happen or am I dreaming? The only way I can think of is turning those two settings off....but that just results in the annoyance getting shifted to when I write methods and if statements etc.

Update:
Just thought I'd mention that I use Resharper...so if there's a way to accomplish it through there I would be interested in knowing that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awesome! I managed to figure it out. Thanks to [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540344/is-there-a-way-to-get-visual-studio-2008-to-stop-formatting-my-autoproperties/540353#540353) I had a closer look at the settings available in Resharper and I was able to figure something out.

My solution involves a combination of settings in Resharper and VS2008.

In VS2008, I turn off Automatically format completed statement on ;

I then turn on the setting in Resharper for IntelliSense Completion Behavior to Automatically insert parentheses after completion.

This allows me to type:

```
bool MyProperty {
```

To get:

```
bool MyProperty {}
```

Which then allows me to add the get; and set; lines without them formatting...

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure this is a problem in VS2008? Because my auto properties stay put...

given...

```
bool MyProperty { get; set; }
```

it stays as ...

```
bool MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Even after I apply the format selection command.

Note: I have the same VS formatting options selected as you. Though I am using VS2008 SP1.

Comment: I'm using VS2008 too... but I'm also using Resharper which seems to be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper might have such feature, though I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: I do use Resharper too...so even suggestions for doing it that way would help

Comment: In VS, ReSharper menu item - Options - C# Formatting Style in the leftmost treeview, see what it's got there.